# Nice plot of f(x)

Tags: matlab, plotting, octave

A user has this nice graph of f(x) on his profile and I want to learn how to do it in matlab or Gnu octave.

[image]

```
f(x) = -(x*x*x +x + 1)
(0,0) = center
color(x,y) = arctan2(x, f(x))
lum(x,y) = sin(hypot(x, f(x))/alpha)
```

But when I try in matlab I fail:

`>> y= -(x.*x.*x+x+1)`

`>> x = linspace(0,2*pi,100);`

`>> plot(x,y)`

The matlab code does not make a plot that resembles the nice visual graph. I understand that I must also accomplish the effects, but can you help me on the way? Is there a program that is more or less suitable to make a plot like the above?

Comment: Why don't you ask the user from whose site you copied the picture?

Comment: I may misunderstood but your three MATLAB code lines are completely off topic. You need at least a `contour` command to reproduce the isocontour lines you have displayed, not a `plot` command. Only then you can focus on the `colormap` used for obtaining such a graph but it seems to have been postprocessed with another software.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using Python and [mpmath](http://mpmath.org/):

```
import matplotlib
import mpmath
f = lambda z: z**3-z+1
mpmath.cplot(f, points=100000)
```

Easy peasy.... See [here](http://mpmath.org/doc/current/plotting.html#complex-function-plots) for the documentation on `mpmath.cplot`