# Contour plot of a scalar function over the complex domain in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plotting

I'm trying to make a 2D contour plot of a function with a complex input and a real output, namely: $f(z=x+iy)= |z^2-3z|$, on MATLAB. I want to make a contour plot of f, such that the axes are $(x,y)$, i.e. $(\Re(z),\Im(z))$.

How is this done in MATLAB? The problem I'm having is the fact the input is complex.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nice plot of f(x)](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/24144/nice-plot-of-fx)

Comment: Please have a look at this answer if it doesn't have to be in matlab perse http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/24144/nice-plot-of-fx

Comment: `[x,y] = meshgrid(-10:10);` `z = x+1i*y;` `contour(x,y,abs(z.^2-3*z));`

Comment: Cross-posted on [Math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2015484/2d-complex-plot-of-a-function-with-a-real-scalar-output-over-the-complex-plan/2015781#2015781) – [please](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu) [don't](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1194/crossposting-on-the-stackexchange-network) [cross-post](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/7652/why-are-cross-posted-questions-deleted).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a mesh over which your function will be evaluated

```
[mfRe, mfIm] = ndgrid(-1, 1, 100);
```

Then evaluate your function

```
fh = @(z)abs(z.^2 - 3 .* z);
mfF = fh(complex(mfRe, mfIm));
```

Now make the contour plot and beautify

```
contour(mfRe, mfIm, mfF);
axis equal;
xlabel('Re(z)');
ylabel('Im(z)');
```

[image: Contour plot]